# Upload file with content to Azure Data Lake storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

Common process to upload a file to the storage is to:

- create new file
- append content
- flush data

I have a problem that storage contains the create file event, used by the databricks, and files are not “consumed” after the data flush.

Is it possible to create/upload a file together with the content? Like the upload file functionality on Azure Portal.

Comment: Is this a databricks specific problem? I don't quite understand the actual problem you are having.

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, when I upload the file to a container via the Azure portal, "create file" event is triggered and the file is processed. But, when I try to upload the file via the SDK or Rest API, I need to create an empty file first and then append the data. Unfortunately, uploaded file is not processed. 
I'm wondering if there is a possibility to create the file together with the data, so the "create file" event will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement using Azure logic Apps through `When a blob is added or modified (properties only) (V2)` trigger. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

I'm trying to upload file to Azure storage from Postman using PUT Menthod.

[image]

**REFERENCES:**
[Uploading files to Azure Blob Storage](https://www.petecodes.co.uk/uploading-files-to-azure-blob-storage-using-the-rest-api-and-postman/#:%7E:text=Open%20up%20Postman%20and%20hit%20the%20%E2%80%9C%2B%20New%E2%80%9D,Create%20Folder%E2%80%9D%20link%20and%20create%20a%20new%20collection.)

Answer (score 0):

It occurred that Flush operation has the `close` parameter, set as `false` by default.

When all data has been appended to the file, Flush should be performed with `close` set as `true`.

That will mean that file has been fully uploaded and the Storage account event will be triggered.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.datalake.datalakefileclient.flushasync?view=azure-dotnet#parameters